# Careers: favorites not filtered

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, bookmarks

**Situation:**

There were 504 jobs in total.

[image: There were 504 jobs in total.]

I have 5 favorite jobs.

[image: I have 5 favorite jobs.]

**What I did:**

Clicking on "view all favorites..." doesn't really show my favorites.

[image: Clicking on "view all favorites..." doesn't really show my favorites.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that...some caching went awry.  Should be fixed now.